# How to Populate Sharepoint MOSS 2007 Reference Data?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2007, moss, utilities

I need to populate reference data in a number of custom lists across difference versions (DEV, TEST and LIVE) of the same MOSS 2007 installation.  Can anyone point me towards a way of doing this?  I am initially looking at using a script (PowerShell?) or tool to populate this data.

Thanks, MagicAndi.

Answer (score 1):

There is the CodePlex project [SharePoint 2007 Test Data Population Tool](http://www.codeplex.com/sptdatapop) that can do this. I've only ever written my own tools to do this myself so can't vouch for it.

I haven't heard of any PowerShell scripts that can do it but they wouldn't be hard to write. Do a search for PowerShell and SharePoint and I'm sure you'll find numerous examples.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on How you create the List. If you create the List through the SharePoint UI then you need to populate the details as per Alex comments or Custom Code / powershell script. In case if you have a Feature that creates the list follow [this](http://jeremysublett.com/archive/2009/04/13/re-provisioning-data-in-a-sharepoint-list.aspx)